# Get polynomial terms

Tags: polynomials, built-in-symbols

Is there a command equivalent to that of Coefficient to get the terms of a polynomial which are a power of the variables?

For example:

`func[(x^3 + x)^2]`

> {x^2, x^4, x^6}

Thank you in advance

Comment: `CoefficientList[ ]`?

Comment: `func[expr_, x_Symbol] := 
 Cases[Expand[expr], Power[x, _], Infinity] // Union`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`MonomialList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MonomialList) extracts the monomials, including the overall factor. You can remove the overall factor using [`FactorTermsList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorTermsList). So, a function to do what you want could be:

```
Last @* FactorTermsList /@ MonomialList[(x^3+x)^2, x, "NegativeLexicographic"]
```

> {x^2, x^4, x^6}

where I used the non-default order "NegativeLexicographic" to obtain the ordering requested.

Comment: What is the name of the "@*" operator? It appears to work here the same as replacing it by "/@". But not in general as in Last@*{{1,x^2},{2,x^4},{1,x^6}}.

Comment: The "@*" is the in-line form of Composition[.].